# WebSocket Server without a Web Server

Tags: c#, java, google-chrome, websocket

I want to create my own WebSocket server, but it will only include a web socket server, no server else. I mean, what I have found so far seems that they extend the servers and meant to be work with the normal server as well.

But I have an application model that works on local with Google Chrome, can connect the other servers via sockets. I want to create minimal but high-speed server to distribute to the clients. Some of you might say that "You get the whole idea of WebSockets wrong", but I am just trying another perspective.

I have found: [SuperWebSockets](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com) and [JWebSockets](http://jwebsocket.org/) but both seems complicated structures for me. I need very little functionality; concurrent connections, rejecting users on criterias, and sending them large data(5-10 MB), limit the bandwith and if possible, need to be implemented in Java, for platform indepenency.

I have network application basics, but I am stuck. Should I write my own handler or use a large library or are there any libraries that can do the basic stuff for me, like multi-threading issues.

**P.S.** I tried to be as clear as possible, I can explain if something is not clear for anybody. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe Walnes' [Webbit](https://github.com/joewalnes/webbit) Server might meet your requirements; a simple event based websocket/http server.  Alternatively [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty/documentation.html#examples) may give you the building blocks you need.  Bandwidth could be limited by utilising a [Token Bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) in the event loop.

Comment: Webbit seems nice for me, thanks. I will try to implement the Token Bucket also.

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, there are a couple of things you can try.  One is pick up a simple WebSocket library and program against that ([Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket)).  For the requirements that you describe, that library should suffice.  The library that I mentioned abstracts WebSockets really far and only allows for String messages.  You can very easily modify (almost no work from what I see) the code to support sending just data.

Another option is to try [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty).  They have support for WebSockets..and more.  It is intended to create highly scaleable socket servers that allow you to easily define your own protocol.

Both of these are Java libraries by the way.  I should also mention that WebSockets still isn't finalized and the [draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) changes on a frequent basis.  Rolling your own protocol is made very easy by Netty.

Comment: Netty is also fine, however Java-Websocket is implemented by old draft.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a thing: Soon to be released, focused on being light-weight and making it easy to build applications. Lots of flexibility expected if you eventually grow your application and no. of users. It'll have a java-client as well.
http://highlevellogic.blogspot.com/2011/09/websocket-server-demonstration_26.html